# How do you access files stored in the tmp directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using CarrierWave to upload images to my web page. Currently, I have it working with Amazon S3 and Heroku. However, I would like to be able to test it on my machine using localhost. Again, I have this working. However, I'm storing the uploaded photos in my apps tmp directory located at:

`Users/.../app/tmp/uploads`.

When trying to display an image I get a broken link. I've been using:

`<img src='<%= bucket.path %>'/>`

to display images, and it has been working on Heroku. On localhost I get this error:

`ActionController::RoutingError 
(No route matches [GET] "/Users/.../app/tmp/uploads/pic.jpeg")`

I'm not sure what to do really, I thought providing the path would be enough. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try using `bucket.url` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using fog? This reply assumes you are.

in /config/environments/development.rb you should be able to set the following:

```
config.uploadsURL = "http//localhost:3000"
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in /config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:

```
if Rails.env.production?
    # your aws config stuff
else
    config.storage   = :file
end
```

in a view (unless I am forgetting something) you should then be able to just:

```
<%= image_tag(image.imgUpload.mini) if image.imgUpload? %>
```

where 'mini' is a carrierwave version and imgUpload is the mount you defined in your model:

```
mount_uploader :imgUpload, ImageUploader
```

of course, you should be able to test it on localhost while also using AWS storage. It might be simpler to just change your /config/environments/development.rb from:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

to

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//your-test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

and keep using AWS while running on localhost.

Comment: I've followed along the best I could. Now I'm getting `interning empty string` I added `config.action_controller.asset_host = "//your-test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com"`. What would cause the interning empty string error? I've looked around the internet and haven't found much help. I'm going to try resetting the local database, I feel like there may be an issue there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: your-test-bucket should be replaced with an actual bucket name on s3, right? not actually, "your-test-bucket". just checking.